# How to report at a certain time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Good afternoon guys, I'm creating an app for android, I prentendo notify the User whenever 13:00, even with the application closed ... I'm using ("android.intent.action.TIME_TICK") in manisfest, but not working ... can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Like:
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
calendar.setTime(date);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

The alarm manager will call the pendingIntent, also if the application is closed.